# LARAVEL 7 - How to pass variables to views

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have two tables, Companies and Projects. A company **hasMany** projects and a project **belongsTo** a company.

Company.php model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'name', 'description'
];

public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App/Project');
}
```

Project.php model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'description', 'company_id', 'days'
];

public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App/Company');
}
```

From my index.blade.php, I list the companies only and I have made them clickable so that when a user clicks on a company listed, they are taken to show.blade.php where the name of the company and the projects that belong to that company are displayed like so.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
     <h1>{{ $company->name }}</h1>
       <p class="lead">{{ $company->description }}</p>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    @foreach($company->projects as $project)
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>{{ $project->name }}</h2>
        <p class="text-danger">{{ $project->description }}</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}" role="button">View Projects »</a></p>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Now am getting an undefined variable **$project** error. So I decided to declare variable in my show() function of the CompaniesController.php like so

```
public function show(Company $company)
{
    $company = Company::find($company->id);
    $projects = Company::find(1)->projects;

    return view('companies.show', ['company' => $company, 'projects' => $projects]);
}
```

And access variable in show.blade.php like so

```
    <div class="jumbotron">

    <h1>{{ $company->name }}</h1>
    <p class="lead">{{ $company->description }}</p>
</div>
<div class="row">

    @foreach($projects as $project)
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h2>{{ $project->name }}</h2>
        <p class="text-danger">{{ $project->description }}</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}" role="button">View Projects »</a></p>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Now am getting a **Class 'App/Project' not found** error when I access show.blade.php. I am having a challenge passing company projects to the view. Any help will be appreciated. Here are my routes;

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('companies', 'CompaniesController');
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be hilarious if I am right....

In your models where defining relations replace App/Project with App\Project. Do the same for Company.... Replace "/" with "\".

Comment: hahahaha thank you thank you thank you thank you, it has worked, unbelievable

Comment: LOL... So much struggle for it.  I followed you question for an hour.... And I saw the problem just now.

Comment: Hahaha. What a miss. I guess to avoid this kinda situation, you can try use `Model::class` next time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to namespace `Project` class properly

1. Make sure file name is `Project.php`
2. Make sure inside `Project.php` namespace declaration is correct: `namespace App;`
3. Make sure class name inside `Project.php` is 'Project' : `class Project extends Model { ...`
4. Make sure you have imported it in controller. `use App\Project`

After all that done you will not get error:

> `Class 'App/Project' not found`

You have correctly done passing variable in view but have a look here for another examples and methods passing about it:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views

Hope this helps you

Comment: umhm nothing, am still getting 

`Error
Class 'App/Project' not found
http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/1`

After going through your suggestions. I have since added **use App\Project** in my CompaniesController.php

Comment: Says `Symbol 'App\Http\Controllers\Project' is declared but not used.` when I hover my mouse on `use App\Project;`

Comment: did your App\Project class mets other conditions? it must be inside `app/` folder

Answer (score 0):

You're already using model binding. In your show method, you do not need to find. just return what you need

```
public function show(Company $company)
{
    return view('companies.show', ['company' => $company];
}
```

In your view, you can then do:

```
@foreach($company->projects as $project)
...
@endforeach
```

Comment: tried it but am now getting this error

`Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException`
`Class 'App/Project' not found (View: /home/tazho/projects_html/laravel-blog/resources/views/companies/show.blade.php)`
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/1`

am I missing?